# PHP for-loop's sql-update not working when using mysqli_query() but echo'd statement goes through

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

In a process file I am doing several mysqli_query to upload multiple sets of information to the database, (different tables). The first mysqli_query submits and works perfectly however the remaining ones don't work. I'm not sure where there is error in my syntax or more of an issue with the PHP code since i am using a loop to get multiple updates. In the comments I have added what the code is for and if it works or not

```
   //at the top declaring the sql queries
   $sql_up_awarder = '';
   $sql_up_history  = '';
   $sql_up_bike  = '';
   $sql_up_social  = '';
   $sql_up_compete  = '';

   //connect to server
   require('conn.php');
   //sqlprevent 
   require('sqlprevent');

  //main table SQL statement that works
  $sql_update = sprintf("UPDATE influencers SET inf_name = %s,inf_email = %s,inf_dob = %s,inf_mobile = %s,inf_location = %s WHERE inf_id = $vid;",
      escapestring($vconncvnl, $vName, 'text'),
      escapestring($vconncvnl, $vEmail, 'text'),
      escapestring($vconncvnl, $vdob, 'text'),
      escapestring($vconncvnl, $vphone, 'text'),
      escapestring($vconncvnl, $vlocation, 'text')
   );
   $result_insert = mysqli_query($vconncvnl, $sql_update);

   if ($vracehistory != '') {
      for($i = 0; $i <count($history); $i++){
         $historyid = $history[$i];
         $valuehistory = $vracehistory[$i];
         $valueresults = $results[$i];
         $sql_up_history .= sprintf("UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history =%s,results = %s WHERE inf_id = " . "'". $vid . "'" . " AND race_id = '$historyid';". "<br>", escapestring($vconncvnl, $valuehistory,'text'),escapestring($vconncvnl, $valueresults ,'text'));
       }
    } else{
    $vracehistory = '';
    }
    $result_history = mysqli_query($vconncvnl, $sql_up_history);
```

when I echo out the `$sql_up_history` it gives me

```
UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history ='51',results = '61' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND race_id = 2;
UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history ='71',results = '81' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND race_id = 3;
```

which when input into the PHPMyAdmin results and works and then updates the tables as is

however when I echo `$results_history` then I get nothing
when I tried to use `Mysqli_error($vconncvnl);` to see what happen it gives me

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history ='71',results = '81' WHERE inf_id =' at line 1

i have tried changing the values in the update statement so that its values like

```
Update 'inf_race_history'
```

is in ` marks but that doesn't make any difference

---

### edit

upon davids suggestion i Removed the `<br>` from the update part and then the mysqli_error() change to this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history ='71',results = '81' WHERE inf_id = 2 A' at line 1

Comment: You're putting a `<br>` in your SQL statement.  That's not SQL code, that's HTML code.  This appears to just be a typo.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` cannot run multiple queries - use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query)

Comment: Also `sprintf()` and your `escapestring()` iám pretty sure they wil not fully prevent all SQL injections, use prepared statements.

Comment: @David when i removed the `<br>` this is now what shows up so that may have been apart of the problem `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE inf_race_history SET race_history ='71',results = '81' WHERE inf_id = 2 A' at line 1`

Comment: No no @NigelRen `mysqli_multi_query()` is a **very** bad suggestion It means that SQL injections like  `1'; DELETE TABLE table` are then also possible.. Besides you don't want to protect SQL injections with a unsafe `mysqli_real_escapse_string()` function which can do more harm and good when used wrong..

Comment: @NigelRen when i use this similar type code to Insert into the database it worked fine but now when trying to update it shows error

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you have any suggesentions ? i have made edit to it showing the slight change now

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I would agree that prepared statements is the best way of doing this, BUT if the data isn't user entered, then multi query is an option.

Comment: @RaymondNijland okay so i see your one with case and end, however it in that example it is just one table that looks to be referred to. However i am doing more then one table so would it be the same?

Comment: "However i am doing more then one table so would it be the same?" No and thats why i removed the comment because i notced you where using differnt tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland appologies i see now that the comment was deleted

Comment: Why don't you run the update queries directly, instead of building a long and invalid command?

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean by that may I ask, im still not so good with this

Comment: Your current code builts up a very long string of multiple queries. `mysqli_query` is not meant to be used with mulitple queries. Running each `UPDATE` statement directly, within the loop, could help

Comment: @NicoHaase is there anyway you could show me ? like write an example or link me to one so i can see visually what you mean ? i kinda get it but not 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli_multi_query() instead of mysqli_query().
It is recommended for multiple queries, To execute one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Comment: does this work if i have different tables that im using? as long as they share the same `$sql_update .=` ?

Comment: Even if you have different table it does not work. There is an issue in executing multiple queries separated by semicolon with mysqli_query() . Just replace the last line with mysqli_multi_query

Comment: i just have 1 question tho @Rizwan Khan, its that  Raymond Nijland  said in the question comments that "No no NigelRen mysqli_multi_query() is a very bad suggestion It means that SQL injections like 1'; DELETE TABLE table are then also possible.. Besides you don't want to protect SQL injections with a unsafe mysqli_real_escapse_string() function which can do more harm and good when used wrong.." how would this effect the code then? just a bit worried

Comment: There are 2 ways to protect SQL injections - one way is to do input data filtration. The other way is to use PDOs in PHP, please use PDO class that is the best way, since it gives you the powerful construct like prepared statements. Go through http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php it is easy to use.

Comment: is it also very nessesary even if i would be the only one doing it and its a backend cms system ? @Rizwan Khan